# ASP.Net core FormFile to FTP Upload problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ftp

I have to upload tfp an image for user avatar. I wrote that code below to upload it. But I have some problems with the given form file's directory.

I have that code below to upload.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> EditProfile(string username , EditProfileModel model , IFormFile file)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var url = Url.Action("EditProfile", new { username = username, durum = "basarisiz" });
                return Redirect(url);
            }

            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
            if (user != null)
            {


            if (file != null)
            {

                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.FileName);

                    string url = "ftp://*MY SERVER IP*/httpdocs/wwwroot/assets/images";


                    FtpWebRequest FTP;

                    FTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
                    FTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*MYID*", "*MYPASSWORD*");
                    FTP.KeepAlive = false;
                    FTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                    FTP.UseBinary = true;
                    FTP.ContentLength = fileInfo.Length;
                    int buffLenght = 2048;
                    byte[] buff = new byte[buffLenght];
                    int contentLenght;

                    FileStream FS = fileInfo.OpenRead();
                    try
                    {
                        Stream strm = FTP.GetRequestStream();
                        contentLenght = FS.Read(buff, 0, buffLenght);
                        while (contentLenght != 0)
                        {
                            strm.Write(buff, 0, buffLenght);
                            contentLenght = FS.Read(buff, 0, buffLenght);
                        }
                        strm.Close();
                        FS.Close();

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }

            }


           other parts of the code...
```

It throws error in this part :

```
FTP.ContentLenght = fileInfo.Length;
```

Error says couldn't find the file , because for example I upload a photo from my desktop but while posting the form the form file has this directory :

MyProjectDirectory\imagename.jpg